# Javascript text search and replace don't work on bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I highlight the following text with mouse:

```
Site: http://www.solidfiles.com
Sharecode[?]: /d/1234567890
```

Then use the following bookmarklet commands:

```
javascript:(function(){
  var txt = window.getSelection();
  txt = txt.replace('[?]', '');
  txt = txt.replace('Site: ', '');
  txt = txt.replace('Sharecode: ', '');
  txt = txt.replace(/\n/g, '');
  window.open(txt);
})();
```

The javascript stop working when use txt.replace commands. I don't know what are wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.getSelection()` return a [Selection object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection), you need to stringify it before:
`txt = txt.toString();`.

Comment: Thank work now. var txt = window.getSelection().toString();